# D.D. Esper Star Sparrow vs Compulsory Evacuation Device

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Let's say [D.D. Esper Star Sparrow](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/D.D._Esper_Star_Sparrow) was special summoned from graveyard by its own effect, then [Compulsory Evacuation Device](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Compulsory_Evacuation_Device) was activated on him.

[D.D. Esper Star Sparrow](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/D.D._Esper_Star_Sparrow):

> There can only be 1 "D.D. Esper Star Sparrow" on the field. Your
>   opponent cannot target other monsters you control with effects or for
>   attacks. When an opponent's monster declares a direct attack while
>   this card is in your Graveyard: You can Special Summon this card from
>   your Graveyard in face-up Defense Position. **If Summoned this way,
>   banish it when it leaves the field.**

[Compulsory Evacuation Device](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Compulsory_Evacuation_Device):

> Target 1 monster on the field; return that target to the hand.

Is the monster returned to hand or banished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be banished.
Any way that a card with this effect gets removed from the field will result in it being banished. This is because the banish effect sort of redirects the monster and so overrules the original effect.

You can see this in the rulings of Dark Magician of Chaos:

> When "Dark Magician of Chaos" is sent to your hand by "Penguin
>   Soldier", it is removed from play instead.

I can see only 2 ways of getting this monster off the field without it getting banished:
- Destroying or bouncing it while facedown (battle doesn't work as it will get flipped)
- Using it for an Xyz summon, as this does not count as removing it from the field